# How to configure the HttpClient from the Microsoft.Extensions.Http package?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) package for my .NET Core project. When sending requests to an API I have to deactivate the certificate validation. Unfortunately I don't know where to configure the client for this. When setting up the DI container I tried this

```
private static IServiceCollection ConfigureHttpClients(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>(httpClient =>
    {
        using HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
        };
        httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    });

    // ...

    return services;
}
```

but this didn't work and my IDE shows me this information for the variable `httpClient`

> the value passed to the method is never used because it is overwritten
> in the method body before being read

So where do I have to configure the client to disable the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` to configure the handler used by the typed client

```
//...

services
    .AddHttpClient<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() { 
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator 
    });

//...
```

Reference [Configure the HttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-the-httpmessagehandler)